# Extract day from a quarter from a date in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

i am trying to Extract day from a quarter from a date in BigQuery.
Any help needed .

For example :
Date : 11-Feb-2022

Output : 42

Answer (score 1):

Using **UNIX_DATE**, you can calculate **days** since first day of the quarter.

```sql
SELECT UNIX_DATE(PARSE_DATE('%d-%b-%Y', '11-Feb-2022')) -
       UNIX_DATE(DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%d-%b-%Y', '11-Feb-2022'), QUARTER)) + 1 AS elapsed_days
```

Comment: Hello Park,

Thanks for the query, its working as stand alone.. 
But when i am replacing the hardcoded date with a column_name then its throwing error :

   ,extract( day from start_date)        as day_of_month_number
   ,unix_date(parse_date('%d-%b-%y',start_date)) - unix_date(date_trunc(parse_date('%d-%b-%y',start_date), quarter)) + 1  as day_of_quarter_number
   ,extract( dayofyear from start_date)        as day_of_year_number


No matching signature for function PARSE_DATE for argument types: STRING, DATE. Supported signature: PARSE_DATE(STRING, STRING)

Comment: Check the type of **start_date**. If it's already **DATE** type, you don't need to **PARSE_DATE**.  Would you try it again after removing it from your query ?

Comment: Thanks it worked after removing PARSE_DATE.

Does the UNIX_DATE function get pass when we write the code in Azure DevOps Pipelines ??

Comment: good for you and @Jaytiger, thanks.

Comment: @Guru, I'm not familiar with Azure but **UNIX_DATE** is a BigQuery built-in function. So, regardless where you run BigQuery script, it will work.

Comment: ok Thanks.... will try later in the script and try my best..... Thanks for your support...

Comment: I had raised a new question , can any one answer on it: Select Fiscal day,week,month in Biqquery